# What is a polyfuranoside?

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology, carbohydrates

I came across this molecule on wikipedia, and all that was written about it was two words: Docosanasaccharide and polyfuranoside.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_glycosylation#Notable_synthetic_products

Answer (score 3):

The term **polyfuranoside** is a combination of

1. the Greek prefix **poly**, which means **many** and
2. the term **furanoside**, which indicates that the structure is somewhat related to **furan**, a five-membered (aromatic) heterocycle that contains an oxygen atom. Forget about the aromaticity here, what counts is

   - five-membered ring
   - contains an oxygen atom

If you take a look at the large diagonal of the structure, you'll recognize a large number (12) of these structure elements connected by glycosidic bonds, hence the other description, docosanasaccharide.